# How to map JSON data to model using Model Adapter Pattern in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a Json data that looks like:

```
{
    "restaurant": null,
    "details": [
        {
            "text": {
                "text": "Tea",
                "coordinateX": 311
            },
            "price": {
                "unitPrice": 5.0,
                "coordinateX": 389
            }
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "text": "Americano",
                "coordinateX": 311
            },
            "price": {
                "unitPrice": 41.24,
                "coordinateX": 205,
            }
        },
        {
            "text": {
                "text": "Latte",
                "coordinateX": 130
            },
            "price": {
                "unitPrice": 43.24,
                "coordinateX": 205,
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using the model adapter pattern to map the json result from an API to the models I've created. **My issue is that the nested objects are not being mapped. Only the the outermost object is.**

ImageResult Object - this is the only one that is properly mapped

```
export class ImageResult {
    constructor(
        public Restaurant: string,
        public CapturedDetails: Array<Details>
    ) {}

    static adapt(item: any): ImageResult {
        return new ImageResult(
            item.restaurant,
            item.details
        );
      }
  }
```

Details Object - no longer mapped. Shown as generic Object

```
export class Details {
    constructor(
        public Text: Word,
        public UnitPrice: Price
    ) {}

    static adapt(item: any): Details {
        return new Details(
            item.text,
            item.price
        );
      }
  }
```

Word Object - no longer mapped. Shown as generic Object

```
export class Word {
    constructor(
        public Text: string = '',
        public CoordinateX: number  = 0
    ) {}

    static adapt(item: any): Word {
        return new Word(
            item.text,
            item.coordinateX
        );
      }
  }
```

Mapping when the API is called:

```
GetText(formData: FormData): Observable<ImageResult> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.getServiceUrl('TextCapture'), formData)
    .pipe(map(ImageResult.adapt));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GetText(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.getServiceUrl('TextCapture'), formData)
        .map(Response => Response.json())
        .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

Comment: I need to map the json object to my model